# Jenkins pipeline with parallel generated build steps

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to generate and launch build stages in parallel for a list of projects in a loop:

```
steps {
 ...
  PROJECT_LIST = []
  PROJECT_LIST += "project1"
  PROJECT_LIST += "project2"
  PROJECT_LIST += "project3"
   for (def element = 0; element < PROJECT_LIST.size(); element++) {
  //parallel {
    stage("Parallel build run on ${PROJECT_LIST[element]}") {
      build_project "${PROJECT_LIST[element]}"
    }
  }
 //}
 ...
}
```

I can run it's stages without any problems, but when I uncomment

```
parallel {}
```

statement I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@3de759b7 error.

Comment: Related, maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36931114/1531971

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parallel Stages` instead of a loop

**Ex:**

```
parallel(
      a: {
        build_project  "project1"
     },
      b: {
        build_project  "project2"
      },
      c: {
        build_project  "project3"
      },

    )
```

**[MoreInfo](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)**